# C# insere texto incompleto no banco de dados

Tags: c#, .net

Olá, tenho uma aplicação em .Net C# que atualiza/insere um texto no formato HTML no banco de dados Mysql. Na minha tabela no banco de dados tenho um campo do tipo LongBlob que irá armazenar esse texto.

Porém por algum motivo quando um texto de qualquer tamanho é inserido no banco de dados o mesmo esta ficando incompleto.

Esse é o método responsável por salvar o texto no banco de dados, neste método o parametro arquivo está vindo com o texto completo

```
        public void AtualizaArquivoBlob(string arquivo, int codigo, bool isInserir)
        {
            string query;

            if (isInserir)
                query = "insert arquivo_blob (html_arb,codarq_arb) values (?arquivo, ?codigo)";
            else
                query = "update arquivo_blob set html_arb = ?arquivo where codarq_arb = ?codigo";

            using (var cmd = CustomCommant(query, Conexao_Model.GetInstace().Connection))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?arquivo", MySqlDbType.LongBlob) { Value = arquivo });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?codigo", MySqlDbType.Int32) { Value = codigo });

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

Algo que percebi na minha análise com um texto de exemplo, é que o arquivo.Length é igual a 723, mas quando eu copio o texto completo contido na variavel arquivo e colo no notepad++ por exemplo o Length dele é 740. Após o texto salvo no banco de dados se eu salvar esse conteudo do banco de dados no notepad++ o Length dele é de 723 e o texto está incompleto.

Esse é o texto completo:

```
\r\n<p style="text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">SAIBAM</span><span style="color:#000000;"> quantos esta pública escritura de </span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">DECLARAÇÃO</span><span style="color:#000000;"> virem que, sendo æData_lav1&gt; , neste Distrito de Itaió, 2º do município e comarca de Itaiópolis, Estado de Santa Catarina, neste Ofício de Notas, sito às margens da Rodovia SC 477, s/n, §1compareceu§ como </span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">declarantes</span><span style="color:#000000;">:- ¿DADOS_DOS_OUTORGANTES_E_RECIPROCAMENTE_OUTORGADOS&gt; . E, assim, §1pelo§ §1declarante§ me foi dito o seguinte:-</span></p>
```

Esse é o texto salvo no banco de dados:

```
\r\n<p style="text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">SAIBAM</span><span style="color:#000000;"> quantos esta pública escritura de </span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">DECLARAÇÃO</span><span style="color:#000000;"> virem que, sendo æData_lav1&gt; , neste Distrito de Itaió, 2º do município e comarca de Itaiópolis, Estado de Santa Catarina, neste Ofício de Notas, sito às margens da Rodovia SC 477, s/n, §1compareceu§ como </span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">declarantes</span><span style="color:#000000;">:- ¿DADOS_DOS_OUTORGANTES_E_RECIPROCAMENTE_OUTORGADOS&gt; . E, assim, §1pelo§ §1declarante§ me foi dito o seguin
```

Se alguem tiver alguma ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo ficarei muito grato.

Comment: não está removendo os caracteres de escape, por exemplo `\r\n`?

Comment: ele deveria inserir uma string corrida, indiferente dos caracteres.

Comment: se ele deveria é outra coisa, mas o fato é que não está, e por uma razão simples, você está usando o tipo de dados incorreto. Campos do tipo `BLOB`são para armazenar dados binários e não texto, deveria usar um campo `TEXT` por exemplo, ou converter a string para binário

Comment: @RicardoPontual realmente é isso, tinha utilizado Blob pelo fato do meu campo no banco ser Blob. Irei me atentar da próxima vez, muito obrigado!

Comment: boa, mas no fim é simples se não quiser mudar o tipo, só usar o método `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` para converter a string para bytes, e o contrário na hora de ler e vai funcionar